# Replacing a variable in an NSPredicate

Tags: ios, macos, core-data, nspredicate

My `NSPredicate` is

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"$1.employees.@count == 50"] ;
```

How can I get a new `NSPredicate` from this one, by replacing `$1` by `self` (or by nothing)? How can I get the predicate

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.employees.@count == 50"] ;
```

I don't want to evaluate my predicate, I want to have a new predicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create predicates from a "predicate template". However, `$1` is not a valid
variable in a predicate template and

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"$1.employees.@count == 50"]
```

actually causes a runtime exception. But the following works and should demonstrate the idea:

```
NSPredicate *p1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"$foo.employees.@count == 50"] ;
NSLog(@"%@", p1);
// $foo.employees.@count == 50

// Substitute $foo by self:
NSPredicate *p2 = [p1 predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:@{@"foo": [NSExpression expressionForEvaluatedObject]}];
NSLog(@"%@", p2);
// employees.@count == 50

// Substitute $foo by "bar":
NSPredicate *p3 = [p1 predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:@{@"foo": [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"bar"]}];
NSLog(@"%@", p3);
// bar.employees.@count == 50
```

For more information, see ["Creating Predicates Using Predicate Templates"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001793-219639-BCIIHDCH)
in the "Predicate Programming Guide".

Comment: I love you @Martin  =8-° <3 _/\\_

Comment: Yes you are right, I was waiting to see if somebody would come with something better... But how is it possible?

Comment: maybe you would have a clue of this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21823339/1670830. Thanks.