# Chaining replacements don't work in NSPredicate

Tags: cocoa, nspredicate

The following code raises a question

```
NSPredicate * myPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"$my_var.employees.@count == 3"];

NSExpression * myExpr = [NSExpression    expressionForKeyPath:@"$my_var.test"] ;

 NSPredicate * myPredBis = [myPred predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:@{@"my_var" : myExpr}] ;



NSExpression * myExpr2 = [NSExpression    expressionForKeyPath:@"self"] ;

NSPredicate * myFinalPred = [myPredBis predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:@{@"my_var": myExpr2}];

NSLog(@"%@", myFinalPred) ;
```

It prints

```
$my_var.test.employees.@count == 3
```

But we would like

```
self.test.employees.@count == 3
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a partial answer, but perhaps it helps to put you on the right path.

First, substituting `$my_var` by `[NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"$my_var.test"]`
does not work, because the latter expression treats `$my_var` as a plain key, not as
a variable.

But you can substitute one variable by another variable, using `expressionForVariable`:

```
NSPredicate * myPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"$my_var.employees.@count == 3"];
NSExpression * myExpr = [NSExpression expressionForVariable:@"another_var"] ;
NSPredicate * myPredBis = [myPred predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:@{@"my_var" : myExpr}] ;
```

Second, `[NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"self"]` treats "self" as an ordinary key, not as *"the" self*, i.e. the object onto which the predicate is applied. You probably
want:

```
NSExpression * myExpr2 = [NSExpression expressionForEvaluatedObject];
```

instead. Now you can chain the substitution:

```
NSPredicate * myFinalPred = [myPredBis predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:@{@"another_var": myExpr2}];
NSLog(@"%@", myFinalPred);
```

Output: `employees.@count == 3` (the "self" part is just not printed).

---

OK, here is the solution to your problem. The tricky part is the second step.
I did not find a direct way to build a key-path expression that consists of a 
variable (`$my_var`) combined with a normal key (`test`). But it can be done
by taking the left-hand side of a predicate:

```
NSPredicate * myPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"$my_var.employees.@count == 3"];
NSLog(@"%@", myPred) ;
// $my_var.employees.@count == 3            

NSExpression *myExpr = [(NSComparisonPredicate *)[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"$my_var.test == 0"] leftExpression];
NSPredicate * myPredBis = [myPred predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:@{@"my_var" : myExpr}] ;
NSLog(@"%@", myPredBis) ; 
// $my_var.test.employees.@count == 3           

NSExpression * myExpr2 = [NSExpression expressionForEvaluatedObject];
NSPredicate * myFinalPred = [myPredBis predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:@{@"my_var": myExpr2}];
NSLog(@"%@", myFinalPred) ;            
// test.employees.@count == 3
```

Comment: How do you know so well this classes? I cast an eye on the doc and they don't talk about that, do they? So now, I just need to understand how I can create an NSExpression `$var.key.path` where `$key` is understood to be a variable. Thanks @Martin!

Comment: @Colas: Yes, it took me some time to figure it out :-)

Comment: So thank you very much!!! We could even create a category on `NSExpression` out of this trick ;-)

Comment: Of course i would love to see a way to create a key path with a variable without the trick!